# Eclipse doesn't support javafx shapes set methods

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

[image]
as you can see in the screenshot, there aren't any set methods or all the properties methods in my eclipse. 
installed on my pc:
- Eclipse Mars
- Java jdk 8u60
- e(fx)clipse 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Eclipse.

You've imported `javafx.scene.shape.Circle` but then named your class `Circle`, which won't work for obvious reasons: when you refer to `Circle`, are you referring to `application.Circle` (the class you defined), or `javafx.scene.shape.Circle` (the class you tried to import)?

The list of methods that Eclipse shows are the methods from `application.Circle`, which are inherited from `javafx.application.Application`.